# How do you list child methods of a class from a parent class in PHP without statics?

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

Assuming a class structure like this:

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $methods_get_class = get_class_methods(get_class());
        $methods_get_called_class = get_class_methods(get_called_class());

        // The same methods are often the same
        // So you may not be able to get the list
        // of the methods that are only in the child class
    }
}

Class B extends A {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

How would you list the methods that are only in the child class and not in the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

One way that this can be done is via `ReflectionClass`.

```
$child_class_name = get_called_class();
$child_methods    = (new ReflectionClass($child_class_name))->getMethods();
$child_only_methods = [];
foreach($child_methods as $object){
    // This step allows the code to identify only the child methods
    if($object->class == $child_class_name){
        $child_only_methods[] = $object->name;
    }
}
```

Using ReflectionClass allows for inspection of the child class without having to alter the child class or introduce static methods or variables or use late static binding.

However, it does introduce overhead, but it solves the technical problem above.

Comment: Adding `ReflectionMethod::IS_PRIVATE` or similar will allow you to filter the list to matching methods: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php